# Focus added ItemsControl item, but not on complete refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, caliburn.micro, behavior

In our `C# WPF` app (with `Caliburn.Micro`) we have a View with some TextBoxes, Dropdowns, and such. We also have a few lists of ViewModels with a button to add additional items to these individual ItemsControl-lists. For this View we created a Behavior that works like this:

- When we add a new item using the button below the ItemsControl, we
  add the item and focus the first focusable element (in almost
  all cases a TextBox) of this added item.

This works as intended. The problem we have right now is that it also shifts focus to the first item of the last ItemsControl of our View, the moment we refresh our data. The data refresh is required, so right now we have either of these two options:

- Keep the FocusBehavior, so it shifts the focus incorrectly when the data is refreshed.
- Remove the FocusBehavior, so it doesn't shift the focus incorrectly anymore on a data refresh, but when we add a new item to one of the ItemsControls it still focusses the add-button instead of the new item's first TextBox.

Both of these options aren't really diserable, so instead I want to modify the Behavior so it only triggers when we Add an item with one of the Buttons, instead of also on a data refresh.

Here is the code of the Behavior:

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace NatWa.MidOffice.Behaviors
{
    public class FocusSpecificBehavior : Behavior<ItemsControl>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.Loaded += ItemsControlLoaded;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            ((INotifyCollectionChanged)AssociatedObject.Items).CollectionChanged -= CollectionChanged;
        }

        private void ItemsControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AssociatedObject.Loaded -= ItemsControlLoaded;
            ((INotifyCollectionChanged)AssociatedObject.Items).CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
        }

        private void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action != NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add || AssociatedObject.Items.Count == 0) return;
            var lastItem = (FrameworkElement)AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(AssociatedObject.Items.Count - 1);

            if (lastItem == null) return;

            if (lastItem.IsLoaded)
                SetFocus(lastItem);

            lastItem.Loaded += SetFocus;
        }

        private static void SetFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender == null) return;
            var lastItem = (FrameworkElement)sender;
            lastItem.Loaded -= SetFocus;
            SetFocus(lastItem);
        }

        private static void SetFocus(UIElement item)
        {
            item.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.First));
        }
    }
}
```

So, when something in the ItemsControl list is changed, we arrive in the `CollectionChanged` method above. I placed a Breakpoint in it for some tests. When the data is reloaded it also raises a `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add` unfortunally. I also checked to see if I can do something with the `Count` of the ItemsControl / list retrieved from the `sender` and the current index retrieved from the `Args e`, but both the `sender` and the `Args e` look exactly the same when either refreshing the data or adding a new item.

So, does anyone know how to modify this Behavior so it focusses the added item of the ItemsControl, but at the same time it won't trigger on a data refresh / reset?

Comment: Does it work to check the count of `e.NewItems`? And I'm surprised that a Refresh is raising the collection changed event with `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add`... is is a custom Refresh event?

Comment: @Rachel Yes it is a custom refresh that reloads all the data. And about the `e.NewItems Count`, it's always 1, both when the data is reloaded and the items are raising the `CollectionChanged` with `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add` 1 by 1, and when I just add a single item by clicking on the Button.